# SQL Как сделать чтобы нельзя было нажимать insert много раз чтобы не повторялись записи

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
INSERT INTO Новая_таблица2 
SELECT DISTINCT Преподаватели2.Код_преподавателя, [Фамилия],[Имя],[Отчество] , [Стоимость_часа],[Контактный_телефон] 
FROM Преподаватели2  
INNER JOIN Нагрузка
    ON Преподаватели2.Код_преподавателя=Нагрузка.Код_преподавателя 
WHERE Образование <> 'Высшее' 
  and Стаж BETWEEN 3 AND 10;
```

Что надо добавить , чтобы у меня в таблице не получалось так когда нажимаешь много раз выполнить запрос не добавлялось записей

Comment: В SQL есть уникальные ключи, при дубликате на уникальный ключ, сервер не даст сделать запись.

Comment: в where можно добавить подзапрос, который проверит отсутствие данных в `Новая_таблица2`, и вставляться эти дубли не будут